# Search Results Filter for websites

Tags: php, html, search, filter

i am developing a web app app in which there are several results,

i need make a search box such that when i start typing into the search text field the results start filtering themselves on the basis of content of text box...

**"Scenario"**

- I get list of registered user on a page
- the list is nicely formatted and tabulated
- there is a text box at the top of list
- when i type something in it, the list gets repopulated with matching result just like "Windows Start Menu Search & Files"

i can not use grid-view as i am not developing in ASP, also that i am not going to use grid view as i need to be able to customize the formatting etc of the results as much as i can...

i cannot be anymore specific... please any Suggestions, where to look, or what to look for?

Comment: use JavaScript. If you've all elements already in the list you could write your own search-method. If not use Ajax

Comment: so it is going to be as simple as storing result in a class\struct, rewriting a container after filtering results every-time the contents of text-box gets changed... that sounds simple... can't it be a lil more difficult

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin: http://datatables.net/

Any solution you choose will have to either operate on the complete table (no pagination), or use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that javascript (or your favourite framework) perfect suits your needs.
Your JS code should just filters matching rows, and since your table is html, its rows formatting is up to you.